# Unable to get Company & Industry names using linkden v2 profile API

Tags: android

In my Android app, I am using LinkedIn profile api (v2) that only returns me basic info i.e firstname, lastname etc. It doesn't return Company & industry name

I have also tried industries Api https://api.linkedin.com/v2/industries

but it returns `403 error with message "Not enough permissions to access: GET /industries"`

i have given all scope parameters during authorization r_liteprofile, r_basicprofile, rw_company_admin

i want industry & company name that i have added in my LinkedIn profile, Any help would appreciated.

Always return the following response with all scopes define

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

```
{
       "id":"REDACTED",
       "firstName":{
          "localized":{
             "en_US":"Tina"
          },
          "preferredLocale":{
             "country":"US",
             "language":"en"
          }
       },
       "lastName":{
          "localized":{
             "en_US":"Belcher"
          },
          "preferredLocale":{
             "country":"US",
             "language":"en"
          }
       },
        "profilePicture": {
            "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:B54328XZFfe2134zTyq"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to ask permission regarding which kind of profile data you need. There are three types of permission as follows

1. ***r_liteprofile*** -   Required to retrieve name and photo for the authenticated user.
2. ***r_basicprofile*** -  Required to retrieve name, photo, headline, and
   vanity name for the authenticated user.
3. ***r_fullprofile*** - Required to retrieve full profile for authenticated
   user.

For more details visit [LinkedIn Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context#retrieve-current-members-profile)

You can ask permission during your app or Web app authorisation by passing `scope` param and pass above mentioned permission as follows

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={your_client_id}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin%2Fcallback&state=fooobar&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social
```

for more details regarding authorization follow this [LinkedIn Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context#step-2-request-an-authorization-code).

I hope it helpful for you. Thank you